# When do you use class components in react since useState is now available in Functional components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, components, frontend

I am not an expert in react so I am a little confused but since the introduction of react hooks. when do you use class components instead of functional components?

Comment: since the introduction of react hooks, you can use functional and class components interchangeably. It now depends on your preference.

Comment: If you need use state, construction, methods I personally use class component because code seems little bit more readable. In functional component you may get almost all feature but have to write a lot more code. Still it is personal choice

Comment: thanks for the answer. How about performance wise? is there any any advantage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use class when there is something that functional components can't implement like state or lifecycle methods, waitttttttttttttttttt...

Since hooks have the state and lifecycle methods **you don't need classes anymore** :)

Comment: Lol, It's normal to use classes and hooks inside same project ?

Comment: yes is more than normal, I have many projects that were implemented in classes (not every software is new) if new features I make sure to use HOOKS, => write less, less time

Comment: But what about redux and useContext? What u think

Comment: you can still use them in hooks :)  redux supports them in the new version (its even more clear) , useContex is already a hook.

Comment: since you made the question by using 'u', I guess its a opinion question :v soooooooooo I will go with redux every single day hehehehehe + with redux dev tools you can go back in time and there is a lot more support for it in StackOverflow.
Show support to my beautiful opinon by upvoting my answer :P (not comment)

Comment: Hahaha Fair enough,  I like your thoughts let me know your Twitter account if u have :P 

Comment: i don't but feel free to comment here when you have posted questions based on javascript, i will get back to you with a good answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Your typical lifecycle methods have been replaced with `useEffect`, which reduces the amount of code you have significantly. You don't need to define multiple methods (`componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate`, etc) when you can use a single hook to take care of them all.

The other advantage is that they can start with much less boilerplate code than their class equivalent, and scales *much* better considering you don't need to replace multiple methods when reworking features in such a component.

The main reason you can still use classes is because there's no reason to remove them - they're still a core part of what React is and how it works. Hooks are newer and follow a completely different design approach to what everyone already knows. [They're completely compatible with one another](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html#no-breaking-changes).